# TIMESTAMPDIFF Format Conversion (Hours and Minutes)

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, xampp

My SQL query is correct in answers alone but when it comes to the format it fails. Like for example the conversion value to Hours and Minutes is 4 Hours and 30 Minutes... If I concat it with ' : ' (Colon which is the normal separator for hours and minutes) it only shows like this '43' instead of '4:30'.. One more example is when the conversion value is 0 Hours and 59 Minutes it only shows '59' instead of '0:59'

This is my SQL query: (XAMPP Control Panel and phpMyAdmin as Database)

```
SELECT 
TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour,ratedemand_datestart,ratedemand_dateend)
+ ":" + 
MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute,ratedemand_datestart,ratedemand_dateend),60) as 'Time Left' 
FROM `ratedemand`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numbers generally have their leading zeros concatenated. You can fix this by using the `LPad()` function.

```sql
SELECT 
    concat(
        LPad(TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour,ratedemand_datestart,ratedemand_dateend), 2, 0)
        , ":"
        , LPad(MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute,ratedemand_datestart,ratedemand_dateend),60), 2, 0) 
    )as 'Time Left' 
...
```

Comment: Can you also tell me how can I subtract that ‘Time Left’ Column every second... If I am going to assign it to a DataGridView.Rows(Sample).Cells(X).Value .. So the users can see how the time is running down